# Group Mysql return data in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

my MySQL return values are as follows

```
{
    "BU_id": 1,
    "SE_id": 3815,
    "SE_name": "Director",
},
{
    "BU_id": 1,
    "SE_id": 3816,
    "SE_name": "Art Director",
},
{
    "BU_id": 2,
    "SE_id": 7032,
    "SE_name": "Regular",
},
{
    "BU_id": 2,
    "SE_id": 7033,
    "SE_name": "Member",
},
```

i want my  return data to be grouped by "BU_id" like this

```
{
    "BU_id": 1,
    {
      {
       "SE_id": 3815,
       "SE_name": "Director",
       },
       {
       "SE_id": 3816,
       "SE_name": "Art Director",
       },
    },
    "BU_id": 2,
    {
     {
     "SE_id": 7032,
     "SE_name": "Regular",
      },
      {
     "SE_id": 7033,
     "SE_name": "Member",
      },
    },
},
```

i tried using "groupBY('BU_id')" but it totally removes 2nd data and only shows the first data corresponding to the BU_id

Comment: Post your controller code and your model

Comment: My controller code  $service = services::join('business','business.BU_id','=','services.SE_Fbid')
        ->select('business.BU_id','services.SE_id','services.SE_name')
        ->get();

Comment: You should use models and eager load them

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat() function on select statement to join the results with ','.

Something like:

```
Select bu_id, group_concat(column_1) from table group by bu_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you require.

```
// If you get it from a model its already
$output = $service->keyBy('BU_id');
// If it is a normal array just collect it
$output = collect($service)->keyBy('BU_id');
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collection::groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) method to group collection by a given key:

```
Model::all()->grouBy('BU_id');
```